# How do I add a MouseListener to a 2D array of JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I am making a Chess program and I am at the point where I am trying to get a single Spot (extended from JPanel) within a 2D array of Spots (named "board") to change its background color when I press my mouse over that Spot. I have assigned a MouseListener to each individual Spot but it does not seem to do anything. Please let me know what I can do to fix this problem.

The way it works is that the current class is a JFrame class with a panel (called "panel" in the code) inside of it that encompasses 2 JPanels, a "gameboard" and the timers (which is "Players"). The gameboard encompasses the actual 2D array of Spots. Below is a relevant code snippet from my code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++){
                board[i][j] = new Spot(new GridLayout(1, 1), i, j, piece);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++){
                gameboard.add(board[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++){
                board[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        Spot spot = (Spot)e.getSource();
                        spot.setBackground(new Color(195, 208, 227)); 
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        
        Players players = new Players();

        panel.add(gameboard);
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 200));
        panel.add(players, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.add(panel);
```

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use seperate panels for this, but, I wouldn't be adding a `MouseListener` to each one individually, instead, I'd have a "common" (single instance) listener which could be added to all other them.  Having said that, we're going to need more context before we can really help you. Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: I agree with the above comment, or depending on your needs you could use a single [glass pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) to manage events where you can just use the co-ordinates of each click to work out which panel in your array is being clicked.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Would I add the MouseListener to the gameboard JPanel or the panel JPanel?

Comment: You don't need coordinates.  You can get the source of the event from via `MouseEvent.getSource()` and then cast it to access the panel instance.  Assuming the panels are subclassed, you can put identifying information in each one to know which panel received the event.

Comment: @aduvvuri007 You would create a single instance of your mouse handler, and apply it to each instance of `Spot`, so all you "spots" would share the same instance of the `MouseHandler`, this lets you do some clever things, like track the last spot which was clicked

Comment: For [example](https://gist.github.com/RustyKnight/d5e3622392f9d02ddf72ff1e78513ac4)

Comment: A "Spot" would normally be  a Square would it not? Notionally very simple. The component *name* attribute is the Hungarian notation location on the board and that can be got from the common listener

Comment: Using MVC, you would start by creating a (non-graphical, non-swing) *model* for your chess game. Once that's working and tested, either implement javax.swing.TableModel on your model class, or create a new class that implements it and uses your game class. Then, use a JLayeredPane for dragging pieces.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried what you suggested and it ended up working! Thank you!